# Square Root using Babylonian Method returns wrong value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to use a loop function to find the square root of a number.
I'm trying to use the Babylonian method but it will not return the correct answer. If someone could point out where I have an error that would be much appreciated.

```
def sqrt(number, guess, threshold):
    x = number / 2
    prev_x = x + 2 * threshold
    while abs(prev_x - x) > threshold:
        prev_x = x
        x = (x + guess / x) / 2
        square_root = x
        return square_root

test = sqrt(81, 7, 0.01)
print (test)
```

Comment: It looks like you have indented `return` into the while loop which is not likely to be correct (it still doesn't give you the right result). What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.6 @AChampion

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a `guess` variable at all. Your `x = number/2` is your initial guess already, and by using an arbitrarily assigned `guess` in your computation without updating it you certainly would not get the right number.

Replace `guess` with `number` instead, and `return` only when the `while` loop is finished, and your code would work:

```
def sqrt(number,guess,threshold):
    x = number/2
    prev_x = x+2*threshold
    while abs(prev_x-x)>threshold:
        prev_x = x
        x = (x+number/x)/2
        square_root = x
    return square_root
```

To actually make use of `guess` you should keep updating it as you approximate the square root:

```
def sqrt(number,guess,threshold):
    while abs(guess - number / guess) > threshold:
        guess = (guess + number / guess) / 2
    return guess
```

Comment: Thank you that has fixed it. Didn't realize the guess needed to be updated every time.

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer with a recommended solution that updates `guess`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

   x = (x+guess/x)/2

as this would progress to square root of *guess*. Change it to

```
x = (x+number/x)/2
```

2. Move return statement out of the while loop
3. initialize x to guess instead of number/2